# How is stored resource type in php

Tags: php, c

How stored Resource type in php? Is it string in memory or some structure ? 
In documentation

> A resource is a special variable, holding a reference to an external
>   resource.

How it works in php environment?

Comment: For example a variable storing a MySQL connection result from calling `mysqli_connect`. To quote:

"**Resources are created and used by special functions. File and database resources are defined by the PHP interpreter and are only accessible by functions provided by the interpreter**" Reference: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=680835

Comment: @GaryThomas  yes, you right, i know it. But my question is how generate resource in php Core.

Comment: I think resources are implemented as integers, and they're indexes into tables in the PHP core.

Comment: It's a `resource` type. It's a reference to functionality internal to the PHP engine that is not otherwise accessible to your code. It has no other meaningful structure that you need to be aware of when writing PHP code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258470/how-to-access-a-php-resource/30259286#30259286

Comment: @Sammitch It is question about internal structure php.  What I need to know myself decide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Types in PHP implementation throuth base structure ZVAL. 
Every type is structure ZVAL (Zend value).

As we know

> A resource is a special variable, holding a reference to an external
>   resource. Resources are created and used by special functions.

for example `fopen` return type resurce.

```
$fp = fopen('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r');
```

$fp - is Resource type, it means in the php core have created composition data by structure:

```
struct _zend_resource {
        zend_refcounted_h gc;
        int               handle;
        int               type;
        void             *ptr;
};
```

Where `zend_refcounted_h` - header of our type, it done for memory managment and represents hash;
`handle`is an integer that is used internally by the engine to locate the resource into an internal resource table. Php create it in process creating resource.
The `type` is used to regroup resources of the same type together. It means we need call destructor of resource and it helps us to find registered destructor.
`ptr`it is our abstraction data.

**Stage creating resource**:
1. Registration destructor with `zend_register_list_destructors_ex()`. it needs for cleaning memory in garbage collector.
2. Register new resource `zend_register_resource()` and attach pointer to destructor. It is our type that returned `zend_register_list_destructors_ex()`

full example.

```
static void file_destructor(zend_resource *rsrc)
{
    fclose((FILE *)rsrc->ptr);
}

type = zend_register_list_destructors_ex(
       file_destructor, // pointer to destructor
       NULL, // pointer to destructor for persistent resource, that non deleted after end request (example BD connection resource)
       "file_resource", // name
       module_number // PHP extension number
      );
fp = fopen("/proc/cpuinfo", "r");
file_resource  = zend_register_resource((void *)fp, type);

ZVAL_RES(&my_val, file_resource);
```

> Resource types are just a way for the engine to mix different kind of
>   resources (of type “file”, “gzip” or even “mysql connection”) into the
>   same resource table.

---

*More details about Resource type, creating, deleting and working in [phpinternalsbook](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/internal_types/zend_resources.html)*